# Matplotlib Patches not matching supplied arguments.

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

been struggling with python and the matplotlib module. I am trying to draw some circles that are not filled and outlined in black. I am putting the correct arguments in the artist circle but it seems to ignore it and put blue. any ideas? Also the figure shows up automatically without me stating draw or show. How can i block that and control when the graph pops up? Thanks in advance.

my code

```
    def draw_lattice(self,chart):

    patches = []
    for x in range(1,4):
        for y in range (1,4):
            circle = Circle((x,y), .25,color='k',fill=False)
     #       chart.add_patch(circle)
            patches.append(circle)


    p = PatchCollection(patches)
    chart.add_collection(p)
```

Thanks in advance.

*** UPDATE ***

if i add each circle individually to the axes it will be formatted properly. If i add the collection it does not work. I have many more shapes to add and i would like to go the collection route. Any reason why one way would work and another wouldn't? I read somewhere that you need to add the artist but i tried that and got an error.

Answer (score 4):

This is a rather late answer but I just came across the same problem and here is how to solve it:

What you need to do is tell the `PatchCollection` to match the original patches. To do this simply add `match_original=True`, like so:

```
p = PatchCollection(my_patches, match_original=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the color of the circles when you create the patch collection:

```
p = PatchCollection(patches,facecolors='w',edgecolor='k')
```

From the [Collection documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.Collection):

"If any of edgecolors, facecolors, linewidths, antialiaseds are None, they default to their matplotlib.rcParams patch setting, in sequence form."

Comment: is there a way to do transparent facecolors?